# Django TemplateSyntax: Two tests with an 'If .. or...'

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to run two tests:

{% if profile.id != 100 or profile.location == NULL %}

however it seems to not work. I couldn't find in the docs why this isn't working. Any ideas?

EDIT:

In the SQL db, the value for profile.location is NULL. The rendered result is None.

EDIT 2:

Here is the full chain. There are 4 ways to grab a user's location. It is a giant mess as you can see...

```
    {% if profile.city.id != 104 or profile.city %}
        {{profile.city}}
    {% else %}
        {% if profile.mylocation != '' %}
            {{ profile.mylocation }}
            {% else %}
                {% if profile.fbconnect == 1 and profile.location != '' and profile.location != "None" %}
                    {{profile.location}}
                {% else %}
                    {% if profile.sglocation.city %}{{profile.sglocation.city}}{% else %}{{profile.sglocation.country}}{% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `NULL`. Try:

```
{% if profile.id != 100 or not profile.location %}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the answer. I'm still getting 'None' rendered.

Comment: First, you can't test `profile.location == "None"`. `None` is not a string, it's just rendering that way in your template. You can test the existence of a variable simply with the variable name alone. For example {% if profile.location %}{{ profile.location }}{% endif %}

Comment: Actually in that instance it is a string. Facebook sometimes will give you a location of "None" as a string so that is the reason for that test.

Comment: Second, you seem to have a logic problem in your first `if` with `profile.city`. `not profile.city` means "do this if `profile.city` *doesn't* exist". You see.m to want just `profile.city` there (without the `not`). *EDIT*: actually that line should probably read: `{% if profile.city and profile.city.id != 104 %}`

Comment: That's it. Thanks Chris! {% if profile.city and profile.city.id != 104 %} did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would throw all that logic back into Python, for example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    [your model fields and stuff]

    def get_location(self):
        [your location logic]
```

Then in the template you can just do:

```
{{ profile.get_location }}
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work. Does it matter profile.city is a foreignkey? This is boggling.

Comment: Maybe if you post more of your code or talk through more of what you're trying to do? Cause the above snippet tests true (I just tried it) if the profile object in the view is either a) anything not 100 or b) has a location of None.

Comment: For one thing, this: {% if profile.city.id != 104 or not profile.city %} {{ profile.city }} is actually telling the template to output the city if it IS None, so I think you just want "or profile.city"

Comment: Yeah it was a conflict. Solution was {% if profile.city and profile.city.id != 104 %} - Thanks for the help Jesse! Really appreciate it